# Shimano 105 R7000 left crank compatible with Sora FC-3550?

Tags: shimano, compatibility, hollowtech

Can I temporarily use my (power meter fitted) left crank Shimano 105 R7000 on my old bike that has Sora FC-3550 crankset? I assume that all Hollowtech 2 cranks should be interchangeable but I am not entirely sure Sora FC-3550 is actually Hollowtech 2. There is no mention of Hollowtech 2 on Shimano's [page](https://bike.shimano.com/en-EU/product/component/sora-3500/FC-3550.html) related to the product, although it certainly does look like it is the same thing (two bolts, typical star-like pattern of the plastic cover) and Amazon [lists](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Shimano-3550-FC-Hollowtech-Double-34-Teeth/dp/B075YY34WX) it as "Hollowtech 2". Has anyone tried it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed HT2. The website mentions “2 piece crank construction”, which refers to this.

It should be compatible assuming the arm length is the same and the Q-factor is the same.

Comment: It worked, I have been riding it for a few days. It is a temporary solution so I think I can safely ignore possible but undetectably small differences between left and right crank - stiffness etc.